# Magento shipping Fedex integration default currency

Tags: web-services, magento, fedex

I'm trying to integrate Fedex's webservices to my magento store. It works good, until I get an estimate for the shipping cost, its being shown in USD instead of MXN. Now, the base currency for the store is MXN, also the default view, and the allowed currencies is only Mexican pesos. The exchange rate has been set properly.

The guys at fedex told me that I needed to indicate this element on the xml:

RequestedShipment/PreferredCurrency

But I have no idea how to do that. Could anyone please explain me how to? I'm sorry if it seems too basic, but I'm really new to all this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That is an optional field that you will need to populate, look inside your file:

app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php

For more detailed answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18551885/4788577

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks. I did check that answer before, but I didnt understand what to do with it. I'm at app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php but have no idea where to put it. I think what I need help with, is the syntaxis of it all. I know it goes after the "TotalInsuredValue", but I dont know what. Is it just: <PreferredCurrency>?</PreferredCurrency> ??